# Retrofit не соеденяется с API

Tags: json, api, retrofit

Ничего умного не могу придумать.
Вот к этому апи конектится http://services.hanselandpetal.com/feeds/flowers.json

а вот к этому нет 
http://mediananny.com/api/category/?offset=0&category_id=0&debug=true

А мне именно нужно второе.

Логи показывают что отрабатывает метод `public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call,Throwable t)`

Мистика или что то не так со вторым API?

тут работает:

```
 public class RestManager {

private FlowerService mFlowerService;

public FlowerService getFlowerService() {
    if (mFlowerService == null) {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        mFlowerService = retrofit.create(FlowerService.class);
    }
    return mFlowerService;
}
```

}

а тут нет
    public class RestManager {

```
private ArticlesService mArticlesService;

public ArticlesService getmArticlesService(){
    if(mArticlesService == null){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        mArticlesService = retrofit.create(ArticlesService.class);
    }
    return mArticlesService;
}
```

}

И в том то и дело что никакой ошибки не кидает. Просто отрабатывается вот:

```
mManager = new RestManager();
    Call<List<Article>> listCall  = mManager.getmArticlesService().getAllArticles();

    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call,Response<List<Article>> response) {


            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                List<Article> articlesList = response.body();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, articlesList.size()+" size of list");

                for(int i=0; i< articlesList.size(); i++){

                    Article article = articlesList.get(i);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, article.getTitle());
                 //  mArticleAdapter.addArticle(article);
                }

            }else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NO responce..............");
                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call,Throwable t) {

           вот это  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NO responce");

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Естественно не кидает, что приходит в  `Throwable t` ?

Comment: вот java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Т.е. скорее всего проблема в АПИ? как то она не по стандарту написана

Comment: Так вам в первом случае приходит JSON-массив, а во втором - JSON-объект. А принимаете вы их в обоих случаях как List<Article>

Comment: а как его принять в виде объекта и таки сделать массив новостей?

Comment: Сделать класс-обертку, у которого внутри будет поле `List<Article> articles`. И использовать его в интерфейсе сервиса.